# Tracing Entry that uses a StringVar has no effect on Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

Learning to use Tkinter and following an online tutorial.  This is an example given where text is entered and then label will update accordingly to the input text field.

I'm trying it in Python3 on Mac and on Raspberry Pi and I don't see the effect of trace, hence the label doesn't get modified by the Entry.  Any help would be appreciate (or any other simple example of how to use Entry and Trace together)

Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *

class HelloWorld:

    def __init__(self, master):
      frame = Frame(master)
      frame.pack()
      self.button = Button(
            frame, text="Hello", command=self.button_pressed
            )
      self.button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

      self.label = Label(frame, text="This is a label")
      self.label.pack()

      a_var = StringVar()
      a_var.trace("w", self.var_changed)
      self.entry = Entry(frame,textvariable=a_var)
      self.entry.pack()

    def button_pressed(self):
      self.label.config(text="I've been pressed!")

    def var_changed(self, a, b, c):
      self.label.config(text=self.entry.get())


def main():
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
  ex = HelloWorld(root)
  root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's working for me. When I type in the entry, the label above shows the same data. Though, if that's all you want, you don't need to use trace. Just give both the entry and label the save textvariable.

Comment: Doesn't work on my linux machine either. Giving the label and the entry the same variable as @BryanOakley suggested works though.

Comment: On the tutorial video (Udemy), it is working.  So I'm trying to figure out what is different or understand why it is not working on my side.  Could it be because of a setting? Version? Platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a local variable for `a_var`, and on the Mac it is getting garbage-collected. Save a reference to the variable (eg: `self.a_var` rather than just `a_var`).

```
  self.a_var = StringVar()
  self.a_var.trace("w", self.var_changed)
  self.entry = Entry(frame,textvariable=self.a_var)
  self.entry.pack()
```

Note: if all you want is to keep a label and entry in sync, you don't need to use a trace. You can link them by giving them both the same `textvariable`:

```
self.entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.a_var)
self.label = Label(frame, textvariable=self.a_var)
```

Comment: Thank you!  It is working.  Is this problem specific to Mac (it didn't also work on my Raspberry Pi); someone in comments said it worked for him as is.  What is the `self` doing exactly?